# Crystal Reports Not Rounding Correctly

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have a formula which is simply `28742.92 / 100`.

I have rounding which is set to `0.00001` however it outputs the value 284.

Is it possible to output decimal values as it appears in a standard calculation e.g. `28742.92 / 100` = `284.7289`

Many Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal Reports -- displaying one decimal in my formula field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836406/crystal-reports-displaying-one-decimal-in-my-formula-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your numeric field and choose the 4th option from the top **Customize field.**

[image]

Once done, choose the way you want to format your number

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response I still get 284.00

Comment: step 1- Create new formula with the value " 28742.92 / 100" save and exit.  Step 2- Right click formula and select decimals to "1.00"  and Rounding to "0.01".

Comment: @tricky12312 can you do some screen capture and put it on your question? Have you formatted the field like I did in my answer?

Comment: Really odd created a new report and tried your steps and it seems ok now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @tricky12312 glad to have helped. CR has bug from time to time. All the best.